# Checkboxs disabled with jquery not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

i have some checkboxes that are displayed by doing a select in database that represents tables of a restaurant. Those tables that are already reserved i add them an disabled attribute. The problem with my script is that i only want to select three tables max and that means i need to add disabled atribute to the other to block them. and when i want to deselect those 3 already selected i need to remove the disabled attribute. Problem is that it removes the attribute from all tables even those that are reserved and selected from database.

Here is my script:
[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hM8kP/7/)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var $checks = $(".table").change(function () {
      if ($checks.filter(":checked").length<3)
      {
        $(".formular").toggle($checks.filter(":checked").length>0);
        $checks.not(":checked").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else
        {
        $checks.not(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML too

Comment: reproduced in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hM8kP/7/. I don't know how to make to not removed the disabled from those that are disabled from start

Comment: Add a class to that what is come from database, and loop through on all check, and ignore that if those are came from database.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something because it looks like it is working in a good way in the fiddle

Comment: i can easily add a class to those that come from db and are disalbed but how can i pass them with js ? and simon it's not working as intended because it removes disabled class even to those that are disabled from start

Comment: As @lolka_bolka said add a class say `.ignore` to the input disabled from start and in your js use this instead `$(".bowling:not(.ignore)").change`. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/hM8kP/8/)

Comment: ah true it's working, thxn for your help guys, stackoverflow members  never disappoint me! can you add as an answer so i can accept as good answer

Comment: @user3058067 added that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a class `.ignore` to the input disabled from start and in js binding change event only to checkboxes without the ignore class as mentioned by @lolka_bolka

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="bowling ignore" disabled/>
<input type="checkbox" class="bowling ignore" disabled/>
<input type="checkbox" class="bowling"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="bowling"/>
```

**JS**

```
var $checks = $(".bowling:not(.ignore)").change(function () {
    if ($checks.filter(":checked").length < 3) {
        $(".formular").toggle($checks.filter(":checked").length > 0);
        $checks.not(":checked").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $checks.not(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

});
```

> :not(foo){} will match anything that isn't foo, including html and
>   body. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/hM8kP/8/)